# passing value from flex to bison

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer, bisonc++

I am trying to print token value in bison sent from flex but for some reason the value printed is garbage in some cases.

lex code:

```
\".*\" {
std::string* s1 = new std::string(yytext);
    std::string s2 = *s1;
    std::string s3 = s2.substr(1,s2.size() - 2);
    yylval.s = &s3;

    return VARIABLE;
}
```

bison code:

```
    %union{
            std::string *s;
    };

%type <s> expr

expr : VARIABLE { caps($1); }

void caps(std::string *str){
    std::string str1 = *str;

    for(std::string::size_type i=0;i<str1.length();i++)
            std::cout << str1[i];
}
```

If i input a string with length less than 15 characters it outputs fine but if the length goes beyond it garbage is printed.

If i isolate the c++ code and running it works fine i am not getting why is it happening so can someone find the mistake in it.

Comment: How do you create a string longer than the maximum size of the string datatype?

Comment: there is a provision to extend length of string first time i created s1 using std::string* s1 = new std::string(yytext); would have given s1 a length of yytext. If i print the value of s1 it is printing correct else the max default size is 11 which is very short

Comment: 11 is not the maximum size of a string. The maximum size of a string is `std::basic_string::max_size()`, which is quite a bit larger than 11: http://ideone.com/7z5oDh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is Undefined Behaviour:

```
std::string* s1 = new std::string(yytext);
std::string s2 = *s1;
std::string s3 = s2.substr(1,s2.size() - 2);
yylval.s = &s3;
return VARIABLE;
```

`s3` is a local variable but you are attempting to return a pointer to it. Since `s3` will be destructed as soon as the `return` statement is executed, the pointer will be left dangling into unallocated memory, and attempting to use it later will have unpredictable consequences.

In any event, the sequence is unnecessary. Flex sets the variable `yyleng` to the length of the token, so you can simply use that to construct the string you actually want:

```
yylval.s = new std::string(yytext + 1, yyleng - 2);
return VARIABLE;
```

Comment: if the variable is deallocated how is it working correctly for all strings with length less than 15 and fails for rest

Comment: @JeevansaiJinne: Sometimes Undefined Behaviour unexpectedly does what you incorrectly expected it to do. Undefined Behaviour can be anything.

Comment: but i tried many strings and after 15 only it outputs garbage how precise

Comment: @JeevansaiJinne: I really cannot add anything to my previous comment. You will find several thousand SO answers which say the same thing. Please read up on [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior): "... programs invoking undefined behavior may compile and run producing correct results, incorrect results, or have any other behavior. Because of this, undefined behavior can create errors that are difficult to detect."

Comment: can you explain how do i get substring without variable and yytext is a string but you are adding integer to it `yylval.s = new std::string(yytext + 1, yyleng - 2);`

Comment: `yytext` is a `char*`, so `yytext+1` is a pointer to the second character.

Comment: @JeevansaiJinne: If it makes you feel better, you could write it as `@yytext[1]`. But in C, that means *exactly* the same thing as `yytext + 1` (by definition of the subscript operator).